# What is the method to group the data remotely for kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have data coming from the server like

```
Id    AppId
1     23
2     28
1     69
1     123
```

What is the way to make it like this on kendo grid

```
Id    AppId
1     23,69,123
2     28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the group feature of the datasource:

```
var data = [
    {Id: 1, AppId: 23},
    {Id: 2, AppId: 28},
    {Id: 1, AppId: 69},
    {Id: 1, AppId: 123},               
];

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: data,
      schema: {
          model: {
              fields: {
                  Id: { type: "number" },
                  AppId: { type: "number" },
              }
          }
      },
      group: {
          field: "Id"
      }                
});
```

Then if you want to use the grid group by feature:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    columns: [
        { field: "Id", title: "ID",  },
        { field: "AppId", title: "Application ID" },
    ]
});
```

If you want the comma delimited list, use the fetch() method of the datasource to build the new data array:

```
var groupedData = [];

ds.fetch(function(){
    var data = this.view();
    for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++){          
      var id = data[i].value;
      var text = '';
      for (var j=0; j< data[i].items.length; j++){
        text += data[i].items[j].AppId;
        if (j< data[i].items.length - 1){
         text += ','; 
        }
      }
      groupedData.push({Id: id, AppId: text});          
    }
});

$("#grid2").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: groupedData,
    columns: [
        { field: "Id", title: "ID",  },
        { field: "AppId", title: "Application ID" },
    ]
});
```

The following DOJO presents both options:

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/ahiCa)**